# tableadapter not updating local database table

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a Logon form that is supposed to save logged-on users to a table and remove them when they exit the app. the problem is that when running the update method in the table adapter, it returns no error but does not update the db table

code below:

```
  Sub passwordValid()
    Hide()
    Try
        Dim userIDAdd As String = DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value
        Dim userRightsAdd As String = DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(4).Value
        Dim CurrentDateTime As Date = Now

        Dim AddRow As DataRow = LocalDB1DataSet.Tables("LoggedOn").NewRow
        AddRow(0) = userIDAdd
        AddRow(1) = userRightsAdd
        AddRow(2) = CurrentDateTime
        LocalDB1DataSet.Tables("LoggedOn").Rows.Add(AddRow)
        Try
            Me.Validate()
            Me.LoggedOnBindingSource.EndEdit()
            Me.LoggedOnTableAdapter.Update(Me.LocalDB1DataSet.LoggedOn)
            MsgBox("Logged In as: " & LoggedInUser)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Main.Show()
End Sub
```

Any help or explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried doing `AddRow("columnName")` instead of `AddRow(0)`? Maybe it's getting confused at which column to add the data to for some reason.

Comment: Most likely it does update the table but you are just looking in the wrong place or at the wrong time.  If there's no exception thrown then the `Update` call is working, so it must be returning a number.  Check what that number is.  If it's zero then there are no changes to be saved, which seems unlikely.  If it's not zero then there are changes and they were saved, so you're just not looking for them properly.  In that case, read the following to learn how to manage local data files: http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989(VS.80).aspx

Comment: I have tried the actual column name and no luck. still leaves the datatable empty.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Its not that I don't know how to check it. I view them via server explorer (db-tables-loggedon-show table data). but how do I check the response number for the update method? I am still relatively new to Sql queries in VS

Comment: If you're using a local data file and that's what you're doing then it IS that you don't know how to check it.  As for how to check the response from the `Update` method, really?  You don't know how to display the value returned by a method?  If you can display an exception message then you can display a value returned by a function.  It's got nothing whatsoever to do with SQL queries.  `Update` is a .NET method.  It returns an `Integer` value.  How would you usually view an `Integer` value?

Comment: Chill bro, I'm still learning here. I have no degrees and no qualifications behind my name. everything I know about programming came from google. So you are saying I should could just add a 'msgbox' do display the return value to the update method?

Comment: Please also explain the correct way to check it?

Comment: I checked via the query builder as well. Still no data saved in the localDB table. The return value is 1. So all that leaves is knowing how to view it correctly as per @jmcilhinney

Comment: If `Update` returns 1 then one record was saved.  If you have followed the link I provided then you should know by now that you are looking in the wrong database and, by default, the right database to look in gets overwritten each time you rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research according to what @jmcilhinney said:

> Update returns 1 then one record was saved. If you have followed the link I provided then you should know by now that you are looking in the wrong database and, by default, the right database to look in gets overwritten each time you rebuild your project.

It turns out this was not the entirely case but it led me to the reason for this. every time you compile, it does replace the older DB but that DB stayed empty, but if the app is run through VS it creates a backup DB of the DB and when the App is stopped in VS, it restores the released DB with the backup DB. this is my own conclusion.